# ZonedDateTime localized format

Tags: java, android, kotlin, date, zoneddatetime

I want to display ZonedDateTime in format like

> 11.10.2022 13:30 (GMT+2) / 11.10.2022 01:30 PM (GMT+2)

depending on device settings. So far I have done something similar using formatDateTime function from DateUtils class, but this function doesn't display

> (GMT+2)

It takes time in milliseconds as a argument. How can I do this with ZonedDateTime?

Comment: Maybe you can share the code related to the problem that you have so far to add more context.

Comment: Which `minSdk` version do you use in your project `build.gradle` file?

Comment: @Vadik I use 23 `minSdk` version.

Comment: Please add to your question more details. How do you get ZonedDateTime object in your code? It seems [ZonedDateTime](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/ZonedDateTime) is not available before Android API 26.

Comment: Consider going all-in on Java’s built-in localized formats. For example `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatStyle.MEDIUM, FormatStyle.LONG)` will in Polish locale give you like `21 lip 2022, 07:13:03 +02:00`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DateTimeFormatter` helper from `java.time.format` to format `ZonedDateTime`, for example:

```kotlin
val time = ZonedDateTime.now()
val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm (O)")
formatter.format(time) // will return time in format 11.10.2022 13:30 (GMT+2)
```

See which symbols you can use to construct the pattern in the official [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).

To implement your particular case, you can also use `DateTimeFormatterBuilder`:

```kotlin
val time = ZonedDateTime.now()
val formatter = DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .appendPattern("dd.MM.yyyy ")
    .appendLocalized(null, FormatStyle.SHORT)
    .appendPattern(" (O)")
    .toFormatter()
formatter.format(time) // will return time depending on Locale
```

The last line of the code will return time in the desired format:

> 11.10.2022 13:30 (GMT+2) / 11.10.2022 01:30 PM (GMT+2)

Depending on device Locale:

> Locale.FRANCE / Locale.US